# Python Multiprocessing Will Not Continue Past Number of CPUs/Cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm learning how to use multiple cores in Python. In the following script, I tried to scrape the title from a list of webpages.

```
import multiprocessing
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


sites = (
        'http://penny-arcade.com/',
        'http://reallifecomics.com/',
        'http://sinfest.net/',
        'http://userfriendly.org/',
        'http://savagechickens.com/',
        'http://xkcd.com/',
        'http://duelinganalogs.com/',
        'http://cad-comic.com/',
        'http://samandfuzzy.com/',
    )


def scrape_site(q):
    url = q.get()
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
        print url
        print soup.title.text
        print
    except:
        print url
        print "No TITLE"
        print

def run_multicore_scraper():
    workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # num of cpus or workers

    # put all sites into a queue
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for s in sites:
        q.put(s)

    # create as many processes as workers
    processes = []
    for w in xrange(workers):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=scrape_site, args=(q, ))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    # wait for processes to complete
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_multicore_scraper()
```

I'm stuck with why this script doesn't iterate through all the sites but rather stops at the number of workers I set. For example, I set the number of workers to the number of CPUs calculated by `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`. On my local machine, that is 4, and my script only iterates up to the fourth url. So, the output looks like this:

```
http://userfriendly.org/
UserFriendly.Org

http://penny-arcade.com/
Penny Arcade

http://sinfest.net/
Sinfest

http://reallifecomics.com/
Real Life Comics ©1999-2016 Greg Dean
```

I was expecting there to be nine printouts since I have nine urls in my list of sites. If I hard code 2 as my number of workers, the script will only print out the first 2 urls. Same with 6. If I put in a number > `len(sites)`, all the urls will print out but then the system hangs, presumably because there are processes started but never finish because there are no more urls to process from the queue.

I am aware that in my script, I create as many processes as I have workers but this was also done in this [tutorial](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/11/brief-introduction-multiprocessing/) that I followed to create this toy example. I thought that my script will run through the entire list of sites regardless of how many processes I create, just like how the tutorial does this successfully.

Can somebody spot why my script doesn't iterate through my entire list of sites and instead stops short at the nth element where n = # workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scrape_site` method scrapes exactly one site - it doesn't loop trying to pull more and more events from the queue. And you dispatch exactly 4 workers here:

```
for w in xrange(workers):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=scrape_site, args=(q, ))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
```

so each of the 4 worker will start, run the method you told them to run, which scrapes one site, and then they're done.

One approach would be to have the `scrape_site` method run a loop pulling sites from the queue until they find the queue is empty.Another option would be to use the [worker pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) stuff in that library and just hand that the list of sites to scrape.

Comment: But isn't the `worker` method in this [tutorial](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/11/brief-introduction-multiprocessing/)  also just performing an action on one site and not looping through the list of sites? That is why I have written my `scrape_site` method to scrape one site only.

I tried the `multiprocessing.Pool` prior to using `multiprocessing.Process` but I was getting a segmentation fault: 11 error. That is why I am trying it to perform multiprocessing using `multiprocessing.Process` instead.

Comment: Nope, it's got a loop:  ”for url in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):"

Comment: You're right. I created a loop in `scrape_site` and it seems to work. Let me know if you have any further suggestions on how I can make that code better. Thanks @Oliver.